# NSMutableURLRequest Omits Authorization Header

Tags: ios, alamofire

From the "[Crud and Authorization](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#crud--authorization)" section of AlamoFire's README, passing an OAuthToken, using this method, doesn't appear to work anymore.

This previously worked with iOS < 8.3. With iOS version 8.3, it appears iOS is completely dropping the Authorization header from the mutable URL request. According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:), it's also not advised to manually add this header.

Has anyone else noticed this change? Are there any alternatives for passing a token based authentication header, with AlamoFire?

Comment: This question still applies, however, I worked around this problem by changing the authentication header name from "Authorization" to "Authorization_". Hardly elegant, but a work around until we can figure out a permanent solution. Note: If you do this, your API endpoint would need to look for "Authorization_" as well.

Comment: Same issue affecting RestKit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958429/restkit-authorization-header-disappears